# Delete rows in Oracle table with triggers

Tags: java, sql, oracle, triggers

I want to delete rows in Oracle tables which are connected with foreign key. In order to delete row from table I have two options:

1. Two DML statements which must be run in strict order.
2. Oracle before delete Trigger on the primary key table.

Which approach is better? I'm using JDBC Oracle thin driver with Java 7.

Comment: You can also use ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: Interesting proposal. I have to attach CASCADE DELETE on the table. Is this better performance wise than the trigger?

Comment: The trigger needs to fire once per row, the constraint could delete all child rows in one go.

Comment: `cascade delete` is an option for the foreign key, not the table.

Comment: On this general topic, don't forget that you can also delete against a view of the parent and child tables, with predicates placed on the parent to identify the child records that will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put a trigger. You shouldn't hide important stuff like that.

CASCADE is an option, but personnaly I would go for a stored procedure which does the delete. So the guy who wants to delete a line has to use the procedure and he (she) **knows** it'll also delete lines in the daughter table.

Comment: I decided to use CASCADE DELETE. Thank you!